# Get value from dictionary based on key throws error - syncfusion schedule

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, syncfusion

In my ASP.NET (c#) application using syncfusion schedule, I am trying to get a value from a dictionary based on the key.

When I try to do that I get this error message:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.

This line of code (where I try to get the value of key 'Subject' and assign it to variable `sSubject`) throws the error:

```
string sSubject = list["Subject"].ToString();
```

Code:

```
    public Dictionary<string, object> Arguments { get; set; }

    protected void Schedule1_ServerAppointmentEdited(object sender, Syncfusion.JavaScript.Web.ScheduleEventArgs e)
    {
        Arguments = e.Arguments["appointment"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        dynamic list = Arguments as Dictionary<string, object>;

        string sSubject = list["Subject"].ToString();
    }
```

If I debug my code to look what's in my dictionary, I do see that key 'Subject' is present:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I get value 'test subject' from key 'subject'?

Project: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/119417/ze/ScheduleCRUDWithWebServices-728709208

Documentation: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5182/how-to-perform-the-crud-operation-in-the-schedule-control-with-webservices-datasource

Thank you

Comment: Please post more code, it's almost impossible to help you with just 1 line of code....

Comment: How do you declare and initialize the Dictionary?

Comment: I have adjusted the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally retrieved the value of key 'subject':

```
Arguments = e.Arguments["appointment"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
//dynamic list = Arguments as Dictionary<string, object>;
System.Collections.ArrayList list2 = (System.Collections.ArrayList)Arguments["changed"];
Dictionary<string, object> dic = (Dictionary<string,object>)list2[0];
string sSubject2 = dic["Subject"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is inside a list, namely the 2nd element. You should access it as follows:

```
string sSubject = list[1]["Subject"].ToString();
```

Comment: that trows a new error:

    Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>.this[string]' has some invalid arguments'

Answer (score 0):

Usually the server-side arguments will receive only the appointment details while performing the edit action. Can you share the details on which particular scenario, you are getting the arguments with “added” and “changed” options as depicted in your screenshot.

[image: ServerSideEventArguments]

Regards,

Dharani